# Computer won't stay asleep

Tags: windows-8, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting a Windows 7 PC that wouldn’t sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/221042/troubleshooting-a-windows-7-pc-that-wouldnt-sleep)

Recently, my computer started to refuse to stay in sleep mode. Every time it goes into sleep, it is wakened right away.  I just reinstalled Windows 8 without activating media sharing and the behavior remains.

What I discovered is that if I clear the CMOS, the first sleep period will last but any subsequent one, even if I restart the computer, will behave as explained. So, every time I clear the CMOS, I get one sleep period and that's it.

Anybody have an idea for what to try next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting a Windows 7 PC that wouldn't sleep](http://superuser.com/questions/221042/troubleshooting-a-windows-7-pc-that-wouldnt-sleep) also see http://superuser.com/questions/519475/windows-7-doesnt-sleep?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/70678/win-7-wont-stay-asleep?rq=1

Comment: Make sure you don't have any Task Scheduler entries that are set to "wake from sleep".  An amazing number of apps you install add entries to wake every 5 minutes or so and check for updates, and some say "wake the computer to run this task".

Comment: Well, some of you think that this is a duplicate of other questions already answered but I think it is not. I've already went through all the solutions mentioned in the provided links but no avail. Since then, I was able to determine that the issue was with my BIOS because I re-flashed my bios with the same version as I had (since there was no new updates) and this fixed my issue. If anybody is interested, my mobo is a P6T.

Answer (score 0):

When this has happened to me, it was a bad device driver. Check Action Center, or Advanced Tools in Performance Information and Tools. I've had both of them help me out when this happened by telling me what device was responsible.

If neither of them have any information, look in Device Manager for any outright errors and the Event Log for messages indicating what device woke the computer up.